# What is the right way to communicate between a C# server and Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, client-server

Ok so i have a C# server and a windows phone app that acts as a client. The client will have to modify settings on the server, receive images from the server (possibly a video stream) and receive notifications from the server (the best way would be instantaneous, like when someone sends you a message on facebook and you get the notification right away).

I have the server and client set up so they are communicating, they are sending each other an object that is serialized with XmlSerializer (it currently only contains a public String field with public get/set methods). They connect over a socket. This works well if i want to send just simple messages between them, but i assume i'll run into problems when i want to have instant notifications and transfer of images / video streams. How would i go about continuing my work in a proper way?

Comment: IMO there's nothing better than good 'ole HTTP. WebSockets are supported in WP8,so you have everything you need right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider designing an API solution via web services using RESTful or SOAP services. Personally I suggest using RESTful web services. Here are some kick start links about REST:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148762/NET-4-0-RESTful-Web-Service-Introduction
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21174/Everything-About-REST-Web-Services-What-and-How-Pa
4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

This is another useful article in *MSDN* which compares WCF REST and WCF SOAP: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273094(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that i finally decided to look into RESTful services. Just one question. At one point the server might have to be ported to an XboX app. Will i still be able to use the same thing there?

Comment: @Squeazer of course, practically any platfrom that can host a web site, can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are looking for two way communication between the client and server then using [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637518%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the way to go.

As for images you don't need to send the actual image. You can just pass a URL to it and then download it with one of the classes specialized for that.

For near instant notifications you could also take a look at [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Of course if you don't really need the server to push data to the client then it would be much simpler if you used a REST API as someone else suggested.